# How to translate “ghosting” (the dating/social term)

Tags: translation, slang, english-to-japanese

I’m summarising a film for class and there’s a pivotal scene in which someone gets “ghosted” by their lover, but I’m not sure how this concept translates in Japanese. I could use a workaround (“she stopped contacting him”), but I’m curious to know if a slang term exists for this in Japanese and what it is? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to sound slangy, you might want to use the slang verb 「バックレる」 to say:

・「ＡはＢにバックレられた。」

= "A was ghosted by B." or "B ghosted A.".

Whether you could successfully use this expression would depend on how fluent you already and actually  are in Japanese slang.  You definitely should not throw in a phrase like this into the rather formal-sounding context which many Japanese-learners would tend to write.

In case your Japanese is nowhere near naturally slangy, a far safer choice would be to use a "normal" verb phrase such as 「一切{いっさい}の連絡{れんらく}を絶{た}つ」.  Another safer choice might be to use the less slangy expression 「完全{かんぜん}シカトする」.

「バックレる」 comes from 「しらばっくれる」 ("to play innocent"), which is a 100% originally Japanese verb.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I suppose with the latter exampes, some context may need to be provided. I see a lot of exmples of this applied in the workplace haha; good phrase to know!